# Sending unnoticed updates to an android app

Tags: android

Is it possible to install an update an android app without the user even knowing or caring about it? I am looking to do what Google Chrome has done.

I am planning to upload my app to my own website instead of the market.

Thanks!

Comment: Whether or not it is possible, it is a bad idea and you shouldn't do it.

Comment: If you find a way to do this you will have found a platform security bug that will get closed as soon as possible. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make it easier and less annoying for your users, push them to install one of those apps that will make it easier for them to keep track of updates and update semi-automatically/automatically in batches (even with third party applications not in the Market). App Brain (or one of its extensions) might be such an app, but I'm actually thinking of another one (I just can't remember its name right now, I believe it had a dog as its icon).

Another option is to make your application server-side as well, and push as much of the intelligence of your app server-side. This is not a complete solution, but if your application is suited to this type of design -- it may help you minimize the number of formal updates.

Comment: Are you building an Enterprise app? And/or can you dictate the custom ROM that initially gets installed on your users phones? May be if you shared with us your underlying reasons for your request, we might be able to suggest some better solutions for you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about you, but I certainly wouldn't want any of my Android apps to update themselves silently. Imagine what a security hole that would be!

Answer (score 1):

Nope.  That's a function of the marketplace not specific apps.  If you distribute on your own you could have a way to notify that a new version is available and give a link to it but they'd have to install it manually.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, any activity that does the actual installing of apps has to be part of an application signed with the same key as the OS.  That would mean your application may be able to download a new copy of itself and throw an intent at the installer, but the installer's going to ask the user before proceeding.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Ninja Strategy for rooted devices. See: http://www.push-link.com